# How to return a C pointer to MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab

I have a C lib that writes a file format. In MATLAB, I need to create a file, append data chunk by chunk and then close the file.

Is there a way tha we can let MATLAB hold a C pointer? for example, a file handle created in mex, and use the pointer for some other mex functions. I was wondering what is the best practice, although I agree that this is not a clean solution.

In C standard, I believe intptr_t is prefered. I do not think MATLAB has a corresponding one. Although MATLAB has unsigned int64, its size may not be the same as intptr_t. For example, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/75524-returning-and-passing-void-pointers-to-mex-functions

MATLAB also provides a libpointer
  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-c-shared-library-functions-in-matlab-.html
But It only works when MATLAB owns a memory.

The 3rd way is I simply created an empty mxArray, and set its underly pointer as the file handle, and then pass this mxArray around assuming MATLAB does not look at the contents.

Comment: `intptr_t` is not a pointer, but an integer. Also its' sibling, `uintptr_t` is most times the better choice (pointers are typically also unsigned). Maybe you should state what you ractual problem is; this could be an XY-problem.

Comment: @Olaf They are integers. But we do not know the size. So I am not sure if we can use any int type in MATLAB, unless we serialize it into a string? (I edited the question w/ more background)

Comment: I talked about C. I'm afraid that's as far as I can help here. I don't (and hopefully never have to) work with MATLAB ...